# How can I use a LaTeX .sty file to get output from a Python file?

Tags: packages, python

I'm currently working on a package that supposedly takes the output of a function in a Python script, and adds it to the PDF. For example, one function may scrape data from a website automatically, so that the PDF can be automatically updated and uploaded to a server without human intervention.

I did stumble across [this](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/python) package on CTAN, but it seems to be way outdated, and instead of finding output from a script it embeds the code in the .tex file. The usage would be as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pythonin}

\begin{document}
\pyin{scripts/script.py}{function}{arg1,type}{arg2,type} %...
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the `\pyin{}` command *should* have optional arguments with the type supplied. For example, the actual code may be `\pyin{scripts/scrape_data.py}{scrape_data}{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask,str}`.

How could I, if possible, recieve output from a Python file with Python code such as:

```
import pythonin

def scrape_data(url):
    pythonin(some_result)
```

yet again, I have no idea how I would go about writing up the actual code for both the `pythonin` module and the `pythonin.sty` package. Any ideas would be appreciated, since I'm kind of out of my depth here.

Many thanks!

Comment: To be clear.... you're trying to write a new package called `pythonin` that will run a Python function with the arguments you specify?

Comment: @darthbith Indeed, or none at all. To be honest, I think whatever works, no matter how basic, would be fine, if I could then work on it.

Comment: thanks for the edit (not too bad since I think that was my first ever published python:-)

Comment: No problem! It was just a few nitpicks about spacing that caught my eye. Thanks for the answer by the way, I'll have to investigate `pdflatex` a little more, I think.

Comment: Oh there is nothing `pdflatex` specific there, the pipe symbol for input scripting comes from `web2c` so applies to latex or tex or xetex etc as well as pdftex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm a little lost here, I'm not exactly and expert with LaTeX. Is `\input{}` just a way of getting text from the command prompt?

Comment: @Iplodman no normally it takes a filename `\input{chap1.tex}` to input a file with the tex code of chapter 1 etc, but current tex implemntations if shell scripting is allowed (`--shell-escape` command line) accept a "pseudo filename syntax" where the "filename" is allowed to begin with the `|` pipe and instead of a file the argument is passed to the commandline and any output is used as the input data.

Comment: See [Embedding Python in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238016/embedding-python-in-latex) for other options, if you just want to use Python -- also [Can I execute python code inside LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598403/can-i-execute-python-code-inside-latex/598404#598404) for how to use `input{|`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given this python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print sum(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))
```

Then running the following TeX with `pdflatex --shell-escape` shows that the python has been passed a script and some arguments with the result being typeset by TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

sum is \input{"|python tst.py 1 2 3 2>/dev/null"}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]