# Call python functions from within plasTeX?

Tags: python

- I am trying to make web pages about matrices, using `sympy` (python
  library) to compute symbolic matrices.
- I would like to write `LaTeX`
  code with the `sympy` expressions embedded, in such a way that
  [plasTeX](https://github.com/plastex/plastex) evaluates the expression. (`sympy` can print the messy
  matrix in LaTeX format.)
- I would prefer not to define the messy
  matrix elsewhere and use a reference, because that could introduce
  errors.
- It should be efficient to do everything within one python
  process and environment.
- Seems like it should work, since plasTeX is
  written in python, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238016/embedding-python-in-latex

Comment: You can define custom Python environment, then you can probably define an eval environment. See section 4.2 of the documentation https://plastex.github.io/plastex/plastex/plastex.pdf

Comment: Hi and welcome. What is `plasTeX`? A link to this software?

Comment: @AndréC Seems to be this http://plastex.github.io/plastex/

Comment: You could consider using [sympytex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sympytexpackage/sympytexpackage.pdf), this seems to be a lot easier to use than plasTeX (but I have not tried either solution, so maybe both of them are easy).